# Can I find an Android resource name in my Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter

I have uploaded my Flutter app to Firebase's Test Lab to test my app on other devices. I need to direct the test devices to log in by getting them to [fill in some text fields with dummy details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test?authuser=0#test_account_sign-in_and_predefined_text_input).

Test Lab is asking for resource names for the username and password fields. I understand that they might be possible to find in a [Java application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#Accessing), but how can I find them in a Flutter application? I cannot seem to find a file with generated resource names anywhere in my project.

Does Flutter generate unique resource names for each element when it compiles to an appbundle? If so, how would I find out what those resource names are?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to do so. You can follow this issue to see response: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16921